# How to install TCPReplay on windows 7, 64-bit

Tags: windows, python-2.7, scapy, pcap, tcpreplay

I am trying to use scapy's sendpfast method. But it requires TCPReplay installed on machine. Without TCPreplay it is throwing an error

```
ERROR: while trying to exec [None]: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Any ideas how to install TCPReplay on windows 7, 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a look at [this page](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/installation.html#special-instructions-for-windows).